# Expectation and Variance of Binary String

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, expected-value

I've been working on the following problem:

Assume a computer generates binary string of length 14 at random. Let $K$ be the random variable that is equal to the number of 0’s in the string plus **twice** the number of
ones in the string. Calculate $E(K)$ and $Var(K)$.

Now since each individual bit has a **50%** chance of either being a **1** or **0**, I found the expected number of **0's** to be $14*1/2=7$. I'm assuming this problem involves the fact that $E[X+2Y] = E[X] + 2E[Y]$.

But if $X$ represents 0's and $Y$ represents 1's, I get that: $E[X + 2Y] = 7 + 2*7$ = $21$.

However, the length of the string is only $14$, which is why I am lost calculating the expected value.

Any help, hints, and advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with what you wrote?  Informally, you expect there to be seven $0's$ and seven $1's$ so you expect $X=7+2\times 7=21$.  What's the problem?

Comment: @lulu I would like some professional confirmation on whether this is the correct approach, or whether I made a mistake. I'm not exactly sure whether this simple rule of expectation is to be applied here, it seems a bit too simple. Moreover, calculating the variance is giving me a hard time.

Comment: It's perfectly correct.  However, as you need to compute the variance anyway, why not do it all from scratch?  It's easy to compute the probability distribution for $X$ explicitly and then you can easily compute mean and variance.

Comment: If you want a faster way to compute the variance, try this:  let $X$ be the standard binomial variable that counts the $0's$.  Then argue that $K=28-X$ and deduce that $\text {Var}(K)=\text {Var}(X)$.

Comment: @lulu Do you think using the **n(p)(1-p)** approach works here too? I was going to do $14(1/2)(1/2)$ to get the variance for X and Y and then sum it up.

Comment: @lulu I see now that I cannot use **n(p)(1-p)** as I have claimed above. While I understand how you got $K = 28 - X$, I'm lost as to how you deduce that $Var(K) = Var(X)$. After all, K = X + 2Y, and isn't the $Var(2Y) = 4Var(Y)$?

Comment: Do you understand that shifting data by a constant (i.e. adding a constant to each value)  does not change its variance?

Comment: I think you are trying to fall back on formulas you don't really understand.  Why not write it out?  You'll need a calculator (or computer) to get the probabilities, but they are all just given by the binomial distribution.  Should be a very straight forward computation.

Comment: @lulu You're not wrong when you say I'm having a hard time understanding it haha, it is a bit confusing. What I'm understanding though, is that you're fixing $K$ and $X$ and whatever $X$ is, you just subtract it from 28. I followed your formula, and it does check out, it is just difficult to picture.

Comment: Ok, so write it out explicitly.  That's what you have to do in most practical cases...real world distributions seldom follow simple rules.  So, write it out. What are the possible values $K$ can take?  What is the probability of each?  It's a bit tedious but it isn't difficult.

Comment: @lulu Okay so for a string of length 14, there is 14 cases, at most we can have $K = 28$ when we only have 0's, and the least we can have is $K = 14$, when we only have 1's, so $K = [14,28]$, each one with a probability of 1/14. K depends solely on the number of 1's in the equation.

Comment: Ah, there is your basic misunderstanding.  The various number of $0's$ don't have the same probability.  If you toss a coin $14$ times it is very unlikely that you will get $14$ Heads or $14$ Tails.  This is where the binomial distribution comes in.

Comment: If this computation is too hard for you, try it for a smaller length than $14$.  Suppose you only had length $1$, for instance.  Then try length $2$.  Already for length $2$, it's more likely that you'll have one $0$ than that you'll have zero or two.  That's the binomial distribution at work.

Comment: @lulu Okay for length 2 then, I have $K=[2,4]$. The expected value of this binomial distribution is **(p)(n)** which yields $1/2 * 2 = 1$. As for the probabilities, $K=2$ is two zero's, so that is $1/4$. For $K=1$, we have one zero, so $1/2$. Then for no zero's, since the distribution depends only on zero's, we have $1-1/2-1/4 = 1/4$. The probability adds up to $1$.

Comment: You think the values of $K$ are $\{2,3,4\}$ yet you think that the expected value for $K$ is $1$?

Comment: Once again, you are using formulas you do not understand.  Obviously if $K$ can take the values $2,3,4$ the expectation for $E$ can not be $1$, it must be at least $2$.  Write it out.  Don't make blind guesses.  Don't use formulas you don't understand.

Comment: @lulu No, the value's of $K$ are ${2, 3, 4}$, it cannot be $1$ for a string of length 2.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I had a typo (now corrected).  My point was that if $K$ takes the values $2,3,4$ then the expected value of $K$ must be between $2$ and $4$.  It can not be $1$.

Comment: @lulu Okay. Writing it out then using a sum, the expected value is $2*1/4 + 3*1/2 + 4*1/4 = 3$. That makes more sense.

Comment: That's right.  Now compute the variance by hand and check that it equals the variance of the binomial distribution with two trials (and success probability $\frac 12$).

Comment: @lulu Okay, so the variance of length 2 is $2^2 * 1/4 + 3^2*1/2 +4^2*1/4 = 9.5 = 19/2 - E[X]^2 = 19/2 - 3^2 = 1/2 = 0.5$. Then, $np(1-p) = 2 * (1/2)(1/2) = 1/2$.

Comment: Exactly.  Now do the same for length $14$.  Obviously the probabilities are a bit harder to sort out, but it's a good exercise.  You should get $14\times \frac 12\times \left(1-\frac 12\right)=\frac {14}4=3.5$   I will post a general calculation below.  Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116078/discussion-between-violetta-blejder-and-lulu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do the general case, with length $n$ instead of just length $14$.

We let $X$ be the random variable which counts the number of $0's$ in the string and, of course, $K$ is the random variable defined in the problem.

We remark that the number of $1's$ must be $n-X$ so we have $$K=X+2(n-X)=2n-X$$

Thus we immediately see that $$E[K]=2n-E[X]=2n-\frac n2=\frac {3n}2$$

As to the variance, shifting each value by a constant does not change the variance so $$\text {Var}(K)=\text {Var}(-X)=\text {Var}(X)=\frac n4$$

Comment: I see it a lot clearly now. In other words, because $X$ follows the binomial distribution, it's variance is $n(p)(1-p)$. Therefore, because our variable $K$ depends on $X$, and $K = 28 - X$, then $Var(K) = n(p)(1-p)$ Writing it out did help not going to lie, you dragged my brain through the mud to get this! Thanks a lot!